# Fragmenting incoming data with PHP Json

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

The form of the incoming json data:

```js
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "message": "success",
  "result": [
    {
      "longitude": -87.06687,
      "start_location_latitude": 20.63589,
      "start_location_longitude": -87.06687,
      "end_location_latitude": 20.63589,
      "end_location_longitude": -87.06687,
      "highlights": [
        {
          "title": "Oh Yes...Mezcal Shots",
          "url": "https://phoenix-cdn.azureedge.net/phoenix-blob-public-exps/1396_Mezcal_Shot.jpg"
        },
        {
          "title": "Playa Del Carmen Beachfront",
          "url": "https://phoenix-cdn.azureedge.net/phoenix-blob-public-exps/1396_Playa_Del_Carmen-Beach_Punta_Esmeralda.jpg"
        },
        {
          "title": "Visit the Market",
          "url": "https://phoenix-cdn.azureedge.net/phoenix-blob-public-exps/1396_Playa_Del_Carmen.jpg"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This incoming data is combined into a single line.

https://phoenix-cdn.azureedge.net/phoenix-blob-public-exps/1396_Mezcal_Shot.jpghttps://phoenix-cdn.azureedge.net/phoenix-blob-public-exps/1396_Playa_Del_Carmen-Beach_Punta_Esmeralda.jpghttps://phoenix-cdn.azureedge.net/phoenix-blob-public-exps/1396_Playa_Del_Carmen.jpg

But what I want to do is to get the first 4 of these data, for example, by throwing them into separate variables and using them. However, I was never able to do that.

My code:

```php
foreach($UnlockData as $highlights)
{
    foreach($highlights as $SingleImage)
    {
        if(strlen($SingleImage['url']) > 3) {
            echo $SingleImage['url'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is all you want to separate the lines? Just change `echo $SingleImage['url'];` to `echo $SingleImage['url'];."<br>"` or add divs, or whatever you want to make them separate lines. If you want them as separate variables then feed them into separate variables by replacing `echo` with `$var[$index]= $SingleImage['url'];`

Comment: thank you.

If you look carefully, the incoming data is the url. and I want to separate them
I can print with "col-3" classes separately.

But What I want is to throw for example the first 4 yesterdays into separate variables.

Comment: Will it always be the first 4 or is there an arbitrary number of them? If it's an arbitrary number then just change `echo $SingleImage['url'];` to `echo '<div class="col-3">'.$SingleImage['url'].'</div>';` or anything else you want. This is kind of basic php stuff, not really anything technical or new. If you're feeding them into a variable for later use then the advice to do `$var[$index]= $SingleImage['url'];` is still valid.

Comment: If you want to stop after 4 records than add a counter `$c` incremement it `$c++` and `break;` when you have the 4 records.

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1):

This will return the first 4 highlights from each entry in `result`. I am using the json object vs array because I find using it as objects makes for easier to read code.

```
<?php
$json = json_decode($incomingJSON);
foreach ($json->result as $result) {
  $ctr = 0 ;
  foreach($result->highlights as $highlight) {
    if (strlen($highlight->url) < 5) continue;

    echo "<P>" . $highlight->title. " - " . $highlight->url;

    $ctr ++;
    if ($ctr>3) break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is ever only one `result` then just get all the `url` from `highlights` (not clear why the `strlen`):

```
$urls = array_column($array['result'][0]['highlights'], 'url');

foreach($urls as $url) {
    if(strlen($url) > 3) {
        echo $url;
    }
}
```

If there are multiple `result` then get all the `highlights` and then get all the `url` from that:

```
$urls = array_column(array_column($array['result'], 'highlights'), 'url']);
```